# Twisted web client IPV6 DNS lookup failed

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

Thanks for the recent IPV6 fix:
https://github.com/twisted/twisted/commit/1c4f621548b5721ae69c4024b41bac3bb12d792c

But I'm getting a "DNS lookup failed: address '[::1]' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known" after the patch.

My code:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest   
from urllib import urlencode
from base64 import b64encode
from twisted.python.log import err
from twisted.web.client import Agent, readBody
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.internet.defer import succeed
from twisted.web.iweb import IBodyProducer


class StringProducer(object):
    implements(IBodyProducer)

    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body
        self.length = len(body)

    def startProducing(self, consumer):
        consumer.write(self.body)
        return succeed(None)

    def pauseProducing(self):
        pass

    def stopProducing(self):
        pass

class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self, hostname, port):
        return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)

class HttpsClientTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_https_client(self):
        def cbRequest(response):
            print 'Response version:', response.version
            print 'Response code:', response.code
            print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
            print 'Response headers:[{}]'.format(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))
            d = readBody(response)
            d.addCallback(cbBody)
            return d

        def cbBody(body):
            print 'Response body:'
            print body

        contextFactory = WebClientContextFactory()
        agent = Agent(reactor, contextFactory)

        authorization = b64encode(b"username:password")
        data = StringProducer({'hello': 'world'})
        d = agent.request(
            'POST',
            'https://[::1]',
            headers = Headers(
                {
                    'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
                    'Authorization': ['Basic ' + authorization]
                }
            ),
            bodyProducer = data
        )

        d.addCallbacks(cbRequest, err)
        d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
        return d
```

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate as a ticket in the bug tracker at twistedmatrix.com; it looks like you've just found a bug in the implementation.  Can you file one there?  Sorry, and thanks for tracking it down before that commit was present in a release!

Comment: Never mind, I'll file it :)

Comment: Reported here: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8071

Comment: Ticket created: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8070#ticket

Comment: I reported mine as a duplicate, since yours got in first :).  Thanks for writing it up and sorry for my impatience!